# Adding a second apostrophe to a string in a dataframe to capture a name that is supposed to have an apostrophe present

Tags: python

So I am working with a sample dataset that looks sort of like this:

```
data = [['A',"JARED.O'CALLAGHAN@CBS.COM"], ['B',"ZACK.O'LEARY@ABC.COM"], ['C',"ALEX.SMITH@NBC.COM"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'email_address'])
df
```

Based off some downhill logic that uses such a table, there comes an issue with the single apostrophe in the string. The way to fix this is to add a second apostrophe to the first when one is present by running some code like this:

```
df['email_address'] = df.loc[df['email_address'].fillna('').str.contains("'"),'email_address'].str.replace("'","''")
```

The problem with this is that the third record in the dataframe, which didn't initially have an apostrophize, is coming back NaN. Is there an adjustment that can be made that looks at this dataframe and adds a second apostrophe when and only when there is a single apostrophe present?

Comment: Adding a second apostrophe sounds wrong to me to begin with. What exactly is the issue in the downhill logic that can't handle a single apostrophe?

Comment: Essentially, each email address is being thrown into a function that does some validations of said address against other sources and the way it is structured as a string is breaking with the single-quote inside. I didn't write the function so I can't explain in depth, but that is what is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.replace()` method itself:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A',"JARED.O'CALLAGHAN@CBS.COM"], ['B',"ZACK.O'LEARY@ABC.COM"], ['C',"ALEX.SMITH@NBC.COM"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'email_address'])

df['email_address'] = df['email_address'].str.replace("'","''")
```

Result would look like:

```
  Name               email_address
0    A  JARED.O''CALLAGHAN@CBS.COM
1    B       ZACK.O''LEARY@ABC.COM
2    C          ALEX.SMITH@NBC.COM
```